# "user does not exist " when calling DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR

Tags: oracle, logs, oracle-19c

I have a CDB user called "MYADMIN" and I'm trying to make it connect to log miner.

```
-- enable calling admin username on CDB 
ALTER SESSION set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true
/
-- create unique table space for admin
CREATE TABLESPACE myadmints DATAFILE '/path/to/admints.dbf' SIZE 20M AUTOEXTEND ON
/
-- create admin user on CDB
CREATE USER myadmin IDENTIFIED BY P@ssw0rd DEFAULT TABLESPACE myadmints QUOTA UNLIMITED ON myadmints ACCOUNT UNLOCK
/
-- allow access to all PDBs to the admin user
ALTER USER myadmin SET CONTAINER_DATA=ALL CONTAINER=CURRENT
/ 
-- grant needed permissions
GRANT DBA to myadmin 
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO myadmin 
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO myadmin 
GRANT EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE TO myadmin 
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_LOGMNR TO myadmin 
GRANT SELECT ON V_$DATABASE TO myadmin 
GRANT SELECT ON V_$LOGMNR_CONTENTS TO myadmin 
GRANT SELECT ON V_$ARCHIVED_LOG TO myadmin 
GRANT SELECT ON V_$LOG TO myadmin 
GRANT SELECT ON V_$LOGFILE TO myadmin 
GRANT RESOURCE, CONNECT TO myadmin
```

I've selected one line from 'v$archived_log' and trying to load the file.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOGMNR.ADD_LOGFILE(LogFileName=>'/path/to/archive/ARC000011_1061542581',Options=>DBMS_LOGMNR.new);
  DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(StartScn=>3083464, EndScn=>3388245, Options=>DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINECATALOG+DBMS_LOGMNR.NO_ROW_ID_IN_STMT);
END;
```

I can run it from the `sys as sysdba` user, but when I run it from my "myadmin" user I'm getting:

```
Error report - 
ORA-01435: user does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR", line 72
ORA-06512: at line 3
01435. 00000 - "user does not exist"
*Cause:
*Action:
```

The error is about the `START_LOGMNR` line when I remove it there is no error.

Which privilege I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what you get when you break and ignore the basic concepts of the CDB architecture and common users and use unsupported "workarounds" (`ALTER SESSION set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true`).

Above code works flawlessly when you create the user in a supported way.

```
-- create admin user on CDB
CREATE USER c##myadmin IDENTIFIED BY myadmin DEFAULT TABLESPACE users QUOTA UNLIMITED ON users ACCOUNT UNLOCK
/
-- allow access to all PDBs to the admin user
ALTER USER c##myadmin SET CONTAINER_DATA=ALL CONTAINER=CURRENT
/ 
-- grant needed permissions
GRANT DBA to c##myadmin                            ;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO c##myadmin                 ;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO c##myadmin                   ;
GRANT EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE TO c##myadmin           ;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_LOGMNR TO c##myadmin         ;
GRANT SELECT ON V_$DATABASE TO c##myadmin          ;
GRANT SELECT ON V_$LOGMNR_CONTENTS TO c##myadmin   ;
GRANT SELECT ON V_$ARCHIVED_LOG TO c##myadmin      ;
GRANT SELECT ON V_$LOG TO c##myadmin               ;
GRANT SELECT ON V_$LOGFILE TO c##myadmin           ;
GRANT RESOURCE, CONNECT TO c##myadmin              ;
```

Then:

```
sqlplus c##myadmin/myadmin

BEGIN
  DBMS_LOGMNR.ADD_LOGFILE(LogFileName=>'/fra/RYCDB19/archivelog/2021_01_18/o1_mf_1_130_j0bo2onq_.arc',Options=>DBMS_LOGMNR.new);
  DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(Options=>DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG+DBMS_LOGMNR.NO_ROWID_IN_STMT);
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from v$logmnr_contents;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    159587
```

Whenever you use `ALTER SESSION set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true` to create your own users and objects, they have their `ORACLE_MAINTAINED` property set to `Y`. This is not supported and can break functionality of features.

Answer (score 0):

If you add another PDB after creating the logminer user, dbms_logmnr.start_logmnr will result in ORA-01435: user does not exist.